How to get rid of visual studio cross platform header E0020 errors?
I'm trying to remote debug my c++ code on wsl ,
I code in visual studio 2022 on the same computer, (on windows of course),
although I successfully compiled my c++ code ,
but annoying errors keeps coming out .


it reminds me that __attr_dealloc_free from stdio.h is unrecongnizable .
I tried including all kinds of directories ,but still failed to get rid of this error.
It seems odd to me ,that I can browse into the cdefs.h , and read the definition of __attr_dealloc_free ,but visual studio still reminds me this macro is unrecongnizable .

There's just "Configuration Properties-->General->Remote Copy Include Directories" and "Configuration Properties-->c/c++-->Intellisense",


If you can compile the code successfully, it means the problem is not in the code itself. Try these two methods:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced > Change all disabled Intellisense settings to true
Project-->Configuration Properties-->C/C++-->General-->Additional Include Directories: Clear or "$(ProjectDir)"
Remember to tell me if it works.


1,disable intellisense does remove all errors ,but isn't that just hiding debugging message to me ?2, i don't have c/c++-->general, I shall post what i see in the question

Since you are debugging on WSL, the problem may be slightly more complicated. I search some info, maybe you can check you includePaths. I wonder that have you ever tried to change the json file?
